# template function with nested type cannot be deduced

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, resolution

I am working with the SystemC library which requires all user defined types to have a operator<< and sc_trace() function.  However the user defined type is actually a nested type inside a template class, because the "nested type" is computed from the template argument specified in the outer class.

```
template<typename T>
class Block {
    typedef typename transform<T>::value NewType;
public:
    struct SomeType {
        SomeType() {}
        SomeType(T val) : member(val) {}
        NewType member;
    };
};
```

When I define the operator<< for SomeType like so

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Block<T>::SomeType& type) {
    return os << type.member;
}
```

The compiler cannot deduce the call inside the systemC library that does attempt to dump the nested defined type using the streaming operator.  Since I rather not touch the library code (outside my control).  Would any one of you experts out there know a way to work around this?

And if there is no clean workaround, would you know if the C++11 has a solution for this?

Comment: Try making that `typename Block<T>::SomeType const& type`.

Comment: Where have you defined your operator?   Have you defined it inside your header `.h` file or your source `.cpp` file?    (This makes a difference as far as templates are concerned, although C++11 supports the concept of [extern template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870885/how-to-use-extern-template) )

Comment: If you found a solution, please add it in an answer and mark as accepted.

Comment: I can't answer my own question for 6 hours... hmm.

Comment: "*but with the friend keyword the function takes on global scope*" No it doesn't, it goes in the scope of the enclosing namespace (which may coincidentally happen to be the global scope in _this particular case_).

Comment: Sorry I'm quoting from the book.

Comment: The problem is that anytime you have `typename`, you have a non-deducible context.

Comment: Seems related: "Template deduction for nested classes | P0293R0": http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0293r0.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found a solution myself. It is referred to as the Barton-Nackman Trick in Vandevoorde/Josuttis.

The key is to avoid using function template. The standard excludes nested type of a dependent template class from template argument deduction.  The operator<< and sc_trace function needs to be defined as a friend function in the template class. This way the function is a non-templated function when the template class is instantiated, but with the friend keyword the function takes on the scope of the enclosing namespace.