# C++: Can't deduce template parameter while working with Nested Class

Tags: c++, nested, inner-classes

Good day people.

I have been given an assigment in which I must implement a Matrix class with an iterator-like structure over it. So, I have the following nested class:

```
template <class T>
class Matrix{
public:
    (... stuff) 
    class Handler{
    public:
        (...more stuff)
    };
    (...even more stuff)
}
```

But when I try to run the following function, I get a "Can't deduce parameter 'T' ":

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T> multiplicar_matrices(typename Matrix<T>::Handler * m1, 
    typename Matrix<T>::Handler * m2){ return Matrix<T>(1,1);}

int main(){
    Matrix<int>* a1 = new Matrix<int>(1,1);
    typename Matrix<int>::Handler h1 = (*a1).getHandler();
    Matrix<int>* a2 = new Matrix<int>(1,1);
    typename Matrix<int>::Handler h2 = (*a2).getHandler();
    multiplicar_matrices(&h1,&h2);
    return 0;
}
```

What's weird is that the following DOES work:

```
Matrix<int> multiplicar_matrices(typename Matrix<int>::Handler * m1,
    typename Matrix<int>::Handler * m2){return Matrix<int>(1,1);}

int main(){
    Matrix<int>* a1 = new Matrix<int>(1,1);
    typename Matrix<int>::Handler h1 = (*a1).getHandler();
    Matrix<int>* a2 = new Matrix<int>(1,1);
    typename Matrix<int>::Handler h2 = (*a2).getHandler();
    multiplicar_matrices(&h1,&h2);
    return 0;
}
```

So apparently the compiler DOES KNOW that h1 and h2 are "Matrix::Handler", it just refuses to acknowledge that during the Template creation. (which is weird, shouldn't Template just instance it with every possible class? why isn't it instancing with int?)

I don't understand why it's not being able to deduce the parameter 'T'.

Every piece of help is appreciated.

P.S. I am fully aware there are potential workarounds, such as defining the "mutiplicar_function" inside the Handler class. But I may be asked why I failed to do it the other way, so I need to understand what's going on here.

Comment: `multiplicar_matrices<int>(&h1,&h2);` also works. I don't know why the compiler can't determine the template parameter from the type of the arguments, but apparently it can't.

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079941/template-function-with-nested-type-cannot-be-deduced).